# Spring Roo and oracle jdbc dependency

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc, spring-roo

I am using roo in a project and when I set up jpa with hibernate provider and oracle as a database, the following dependency is inserted automatically:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

In our nexus repository we have the following artifact:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I change the dependency to reflect my needs, roo continues to complain about the previous unresolved dependency.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually guys for my case it seems like a bug in sts suite. As soon as I manually removed the dependency and added mine (via the roo shell) everything worked ok!

Answer (score 0):

Does Roo complain or is it a maven problem? In the second case, you have to add your nexus repository to the pom, or even installing the desired driver (mvn install-file or something like that)